# Error en React al usar styled components

Tags: reactjs, vscode, styled-components

Estaba haciendo un proyecto de React en VScode y todo iba bien hasta que he usado el styled components. De repente me ha salido este error:

null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useDebugValue')

Este es el código:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled- 
components'

const Container = styled.div`
height: 20px;
background-color: purple;
`

function Barra() {
return (
<Container>Ejemplo</Container>
  )
 }

 export default Barra
```

Alguien sabe si he cometido algún error? He intentado actualizar tanto React como styled components y no se ha solucionado

Comment: npm install react@latest // 
npm install react-dom@latest

Comment: @ferter3006 He probado ambos y el problema persiste. Agradezco mucho tu aporte.

Comment: No se, la docuemntacion está bastante clara y hay actualizaciones casis semanales, deberia de funcioanr bien. Dale esto:  npm install styled-components@^5.0.0 react@^16.8 react-dom@^16.8 react-is@^16.8

Comment: luego copia este ejemplo de la documetnación y usalo cal tual, para comprobar que als dependencias esten correctamente instaladas. https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components#:~:text=import%20React%20from,/Wrapper%3E